# Python - Sum values on duplicates in dictonary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file looking like this, it contains a name + last name and a score for each person.

```
Martin Johansson 1
Maria Smith 3
James Anderson 0
Karl Miller 2
Robert Wilson 1
Maria Smith 2
Maria Smith 1
```

I have mapped the names and score into a dict, how can I sum the score on ex. Maria Smith which is a duplicate.
The goal is that the code should print out the person with most points, in this case it would be Maria Smith.

My code

```
    import collections

names = []
points = []
totalScore = 0
with open("score3.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split(" ")
        names.append(splitLine[2] + " " + splitLine[3])
        points.append(int(splitLine[4]))

# Maps my names and points together
content_list = dict(zip(names, points))


# Check for duplicates
duplicates = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(names).items() if count > 1]
```

So something like this

```
if duplicates  == True:
   totalScore = sum(item[points] for item in content_list) 
print(totalScore)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your dictionary, you lose the duplicate information - only the last one of each multiplicity is kept.

The solution you are looking for is to do the aggregate sums beforehands or directly as you are creating the dictionary:

```
content_list = {}
for (name, score) in zip(names,points):
    if name in content_list.keys():
        #if the value is already in list, add current score to the sum
        content_list[name] += score
    else:
        #if the value is not yet in list, create an entry
        content_list[name] = score
```

Faster way of doing this would be to prepare the list of names to ensure the dictionary has all the keys and then do the aggregation. But if you are not in dire need of a fast solution this one is rather straightforward.(and not even that slow)

Comment: Just to add, `content_list = defaultdict(int)` could also be used to reduce the total amount of lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also.

```
content_dict = {}
for name, score in zip(names,points):
    value = content_dict.setdefault(name, 0)
    content_dict[name] = value + score
```

Comment: Can also just be `content_dict[name] = content_dict.get(name, 0) + score`

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

in dictionary the duplicate values only the last one comes as an output it does not matter if it is the biggest or smallest